# mtrace doesn't generate mtrace data file in archlinux but works in debian

Tags: gcc, archlinux, mtrace

I use mtrace as [mtrace example in archlinux manual](https://man.archlinux.org/man/mtrace.3.en#EXAMPLES), whereas it doesn't generate mtrace data file `/tmp/t`.

mtrace info:

```
mtrace (GNU libc) 2.36
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Ulrich Drepper <drepper@gnu.org>
```

glibc info:

```
local/glibc 2.36-6
    GNU C Library
```

gcc info:

```
gcc (GCC) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

archlinux info:

```
Linux ArchLinux 6.0.2-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat, 15 Oct 2022 14:00:49 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: This also doesn't work on Fedora 38.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add environment variable `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libc_malloc_debug.so` (or similar depending on your libc path) when running the program.

I found this [reported in the Arch bug tracker](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/76435), which further links to `glibc.git/NEWS` [item](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=NEWS;h=a10bb08fb09cf7d323826cc66bdd665232c1ed96;hb=HEAD#l723), which says the following:

> Debugging features in malloc such as the MALLOC_CHECK_ environment variable
> (or the glibc.malloc.check tunable), mtrace() and mcheck() have now been
> disabled by default in the main C library.  Users looking to use these
> features now need to preload a new debugging DSO libc_malloc_debug.so to get
> this functionality back.